# Joining to individual records of a Group By query

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate, common-table-expression

I have 2 source tables -- GroupEvent and GroupEventAttendance.

GroupEvent looks something like this:

| EventID | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Event1-SubEventA |
| 2 | Event1-SubEventB |
| 3 | Event2-SubEventA |
| 4 | Event2-SubEventB |

GroupEventAttendance:

| EventID | PersonID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 15 |
| 2 | 16 |
| 3 | 18 |
| 3 | 19 |
| 4 | 21 |
| 4 | 22 |

These two tables join but EventID BUT...

I need to merge groupEvents in the source table under various conditions. I have a scalar valued function for that in conjunction with a Group By query -- looks like this:

```
SELECT 'G-' + STRING_AGG(CAST(EventID AS varchar(10)),'-') AS mergedEventID, 
dbo.fnGetGroupName(Notes,Description) AS Group_name
FROM GroupEvent
GROUP BY dbo.fnGetGroupName(Notes,Description)
```

This produces results that look like this:

| mergedEventID | Group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1-2 | Event1 |
| 3-4 | Event2 |

Now... I need to join the GroupEventAttendance table based on the original EventID...which can't be in the Group By table.

The desired output for GroupEventAttendance table would look like this:

| EventID | PersonID |
| --- | --- |
| 1-2 | 12 |
| 1-2 | 13 |
| 1-2 | 15 |
| 1-2 | 16 |
| 3-4 | 18 |
| 3-4 | 19 |
| 3-4 | 21 |
| 3-4 | 22 |

Any suggestions for the most graceful way to link the GroupEventAttendance to pull the merged eventID?

Considering CTE, Stored Proc, function... I know I'll get this, but in a pinch for time...

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY eliminates all duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh...yes! thank you...that was a remnant from the query before adding GROUP BY...will remove that.

Answer (score 0):

I would still welcome an answers out of curiosity, but here's what I did.

I ended up removing the Group By altogether and using the GroupName without spaces as the mergedEventID.

SELECT DISTINCT REPLACE(dbo.fnGetGroupName(Notes,Description),' ','')           AS Group_id

,EventID

,dbo.fnGetRemindGroupName(Notes,Description)                        AS group_name

FROM GroupEvent
WHERE {conditions}

This allows for EventID to be included and available to join with the EventAttendance table. Output looks like this:

| MergedEventID | GroupName | OriginalEventID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| EVENT1NAME | Event 1 | 1 |
| EVENT1NAME | Event 1 | 2 |
| EVENT2NAME | Event 2 | 3 |
| EVENT2NAME | Event 2 | 4 |

I know this is pretty straight-forward...was just thinking there would be some more clever/eloquent way to do this.